# problem of displaying geojson file with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis, geojson

I want to display the attributes of a shapefile layer using leaflet, I found that should i to convert the layer from shp to GeoJson. I can display the popups of my layers but the large layers can not displayed and the computer is not responding.
what is the solution?

Comment: Depends on how much data there is. Maybe VectorGrid.Slicer can help, maybe you'll need to tile the data in some other way.

Comment: have your an other way to display popup of any layer with leaflet please?